# When does an automorphism extend to a localisation (noncommutative rings)

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, localization, noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a (not necessarily commutative) ring. Let $\tau$ be an automorphism of $R$. Consider the localisation of $R$ at a set of multiplicative elements which satisfy the ore condition, say $X$. When does $\tau$ extend to $RX^{-1}$?

My thoughts:
Since any element of $RX^{-1}$ is of the form $rx^{-1}$, where $r\in R$ and $x\in X$, we are really asking: When is $\tau(x)^{-1}$ defined? This is definitely defined if $X$ is invariant under $\tau$ but is this it? What if $\tau(x)=ux$ where $u$ is a unit in $R$? This seems fine too. But here $X$ is not left invariant. Can anyone help me with the necessary and sufficient conditions?

Comment: Are you assuming the right Ore condition, or some two-sided Ore condition?  Are you assuming that $X$ consists of regular elements, or are you allowing zero-divisors?  Finally, what have you done to try to approach this problem?

Comment: The universal property of localization answers the question.